# how to Run Websocket in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website where i am using **websocket** i have to run my website on IE also but *IE does not support websocket* is there any way to run the websocket on IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE Versions < 10 do not support Websockets, but you can use alternative techniques like flash or ajax-longpolling.

I recommend you to use a Framework so you don't have to take care of all the cross browser issues. A very good framework for this is [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Edit 2017: this should probably not be an issue anymore, since websockets are now basically [supported across the board](http://caniuse.com/#search=Websocket).

Comment: note that if you this you have to change your whole system (all browsers, and the server too) to use socket.io instead of native WebSockets.

Comment: @Alnitak Well, I guess it might be the same work like you have to spend if you want to make your native WebSockets run properly in IE:-D

Comment: @Christoph I heard many times that IE doesn't support websockets and I tested that in my browser IE 10 found it showing 'websocket undefined'.
But this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673567(v=vs.85).aspx) says IE does support websockets, can u please lemme know the truth?

Comment: @AryanVenkat thanks for you comment. At the time I wrote the comment, the release of IE 10 was still a couple of months away, so I didn't take this into account. I now rephrased my answer to take into account, that IE10 *does* support Websockets. To confirm this, type `WebSocket` in the console (mind the CamelCase, as it is an Object!) and you will see, that it is present indeed. You were promted undefined simply because of the wrong case.

Comment: is it possible to have a result from the WebSocket when you open it with explorer 9 or less? like 'undefined', so i could put a condition lik if(websocket){do something}

Answer (score 0):

You can download the webpage source code that runs in Chrome, Firefox, and IE (at least) via the blog article "[Websocket Server Demonstration](http://highlevellogic.blogspot.se/2011/09/websocket-server-demonstration_26.html)" from the High Level Logic Project. The webpage is set up for developers.

Make sure you also click and read "(UPDATE: Demo on MSIE)" linke in the article. Following the  simple instructions will load the google plugin that will allow you to run up-to-date websockets in IE.